# vue components visible in production deployment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have made a Vue JS App using the Vue-cli 3. I then deployed the app to my website  and everything was fine. When I looked at the source of the website I saw this webpack folder.
[image]

I asked myself why all my components are visible there. I searched a lot about this but didn't find anything for this. My question is if this is meant to be like this and if I could deploy my Vue JS App without my Components being visible in the source.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that these files don't actually exist and they're coming from the source map. Click on one of the files and take a look at the bottom of the dev tools, you may well see it say where they've been mapped from.

Comment: Oh yeah there is a text : (source mapped from app.e2425284.js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want source maps in production builds you should be able to turn them off using `productionSourceMap: false` in your `vue.config.js`.

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#productionsourcemap

This setting can also be changed via the CLI UI by running `vue ui`.

Comment: where can I find the vue.config.js file?

Comment: @calledmaxi It may not currently exist. See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js. You may find it easier to use the UI.

Comment: Is there a way to edit this in the package.json file?

Comment: @calledmaxi I haven't tried that myself but according to the link I just posted it can be configured in `package.json`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did it via the CLI UI.

Comment: My Vue JS App is now much smaller (250kb instead of 900kb) and the website loads even faster!